# Should js Cannot read property 'should' of null

Tags: node.js, should.js

i try to use the testing tool mocha in node. Consider the following test scenario

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.config({
    //Pass the top-level main.js/index.js require
    //function to requirejs so that node modules
    //are loaded relative to the top-level JS file.
    nodeRequire: require
});


describe('Testing controller', function () {

    it('Should be pass', function (done) {
            (4).should.equal(4);
            done();
    });

    it('Should avoid name king', function (done) {
        requirejs(['../server/libs/validate_name'], function (validateName) {
            var err_test, accountExists_test, notAllow_test, available_test;
            validateName('anu', function (err, accountExists, notAllow, available) {
                accountExists.should.not.be.true;
                done();
            });

        });
    });

});
```

as a testing result i have got:

```
$ make test
./node_modules/.bin/mocha \
                --reporter list

  . Testing controller Should be pass: 0ms
  1) Testing controller Should avoid name anu

  1 passing (560 ms)
  1 failing

  1) Testing controller Should avoid name anu:
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'should' of null
      at d:\townspeech\test\test.spec.js:23:30
      at d:\townspeech\server\libs\validate_name.js:31:20
      at d:\townspeech\test\test.spec.js:22:13
      at Object.context.execCb (d:\townspeech\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1869:33)
      at Object.Module.check (d:\townspeech\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1105:51)
      at Object.Module.enable (d:\townspeech\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1376:22)
      at Object.Module.init (d:\townspeech\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1013:26)
      at null._onTimeout (d:\townspeech\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1646:36)
      at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)



make: *** [test] Error 1
```

The first pass without any complication but the second, it seems like, that could not attach module shouldjs. Why?

Comment: It's cus accountExists is null, and there's no properties on null. Can you use [expect](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) too? If so `expect(accountExists).to.not.equal(true)` would work.

Comment: You can also use should.not.exist(accountExists);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a known problem with the `should` library: As it extends `object`, of course it only works when you have a concrete object. As `null`, by definition, means that you don't have an object, you can not call any methods on it or access any of its properties.

Hence, `should` is not available in this case.

Basically, you have two options of how to deal with this:

1. You could exchange `actual` and `expected`. This way, as long as you do not expect `null`, you have an object in the beginning and hence can access its `should` property. But, this is not nice, as it changes semantics, and does not work in all cases.
2. You could exchange the `should` library by another assertion library that does not have this problem.

Personally, I'd go with option 2, and my highly subjective personal favorite for this is [node-assertthat](https://github.com/goloroden/node-assertthat) (which has been written by me, hence it's my favorite).

Anyway, there are lots of other options, such as [expect](https://github.com/LearnBoost/expect.js). Feel free to use any of these assertion libraries that best suits your style of writing tests.

Comment: You can use shuold to test for null objects with should.exists(object)

Comment: good call, @zaboco. ```should.exist(object)``` is the correct method to call. I can't actually edit my comment thought :(

Comment: Don't you mean `should.not.exist(possibleNullVariable)` since you are testing for null?

Answer (score 79):

I had the same problem. I solved it by using:

`(err === null).should.be.true;`

Comment: Like it) I use also  `(!res).should.be.ok();`

Comment: in version 8.2.2, `true` is a function and must be like `(err === null).should.be.true()` to make it work

Comment: Or use `(err === null).should.equal(true)` would be nicer, because `true` is not actually a verb

Comment: This did not work for me. It always returned true even if err is a non-null string. However, `(err === null).should.equal(true)` worked as expected

Answer (score 31):

You can use should directly

```
should.not.exist(err);
```

Comment: `should.not.exist(err);`
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Assertion> has no method 'exist'

Comment: You need to use `const should = chai.should();` to define `should`.

Comment: This is directly from the ShouldJS documentation: https://shouldjs.github.io/#should-exist

Answer (score 7):

One more option that I don't see mentioned here:

```
should(err === null).be.null
```

In you example that would would be:

```
should(accountExists).be.null
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'should' of object #<Object> is not a function

Comment: @FelikZ you would have to show some code to give that error some context. Did you remember to require() should?

Comment: yes should required. That error comes only with null and undefined variables. Other shoulds works as expected. Working solution for me is the post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19994851/734493

Answer (score 1):

I always find `expect` works better with `null` and `undefined` as follows:

`expect(err).be.null`